# Fatal Error, MySQL server has gone away with a php joined query

Tags: php, mysql, fatal-error

Yesterday my website worked like a charm and today, I got this error message... I made an update but I didn't touch that query, and even if I had, the website worked fine after the update so... I don't understand why this is happening...

Do you see something I could have miss or miss understand in my query or in the error message ?

#### Here is the ugly error

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 2006 MySQL server has gone away' in /homepages/1/d502435265/htdocs/pages/parametres/php/set_home.php:11 Stack trace: #0 /homepages/1/d502435265/htdocs/pages/parametres/php/set_home.php(11): PDO->query('SELECT projet.t...') #1 /homepages/1/d502435265/htdocs/pages/home.php(28): include('/homepages/1/d5...') #2 {main} thrown in /homepages/1/d502435265/htdocs/pages/parametres/php/set_home.php on line 11
```

#### Here is my php file

```
$project = array();
$i = 0;
$ask = $bdd->query("SELECT projet.titre AS titre, projet.id AS id, tag.titre AS tagname, DATE_FORMAT(projet.date_creation, \'%d/%m/%Y\') AS date
FROM projet
INNER JOIN tag
ON projet.id_tag = tag.id
ORDER BY date DESC");
while ($data = $ask->fetch()) 
{
    $project[$i]['titre'] = $data['titre'];
    $project[$i]['id'] = $data['id'];

    if($lang == 'fr'){
        $project[$i]['tagname'] = $data['tagname'];
    }

    else {
        for ($j = 0; $j < count($compare); $j++) {
            if($data['tagname'] == $compare[$j][0]){
                $project[$i]['tagname'] = $compare[$j][1];
            }
        }
    }

    $project[$i]['date'] = $data['date'];

    $ask2 = $bdd->prepare('SELECT * FROM photo_projet WHERE id_projet = ? HAVING position = 0');
    $ask2->execute(array($data['id']));
    $data2 = $ask2->fetch();
    $project[$i]['photo_src'] = $data2['photo_src'];
    $ask2->closeCursor();

    $i++;
}
$ask->closeCursor();
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps you reached the point with data growth or some intermittent issue and that just timed out. It is obviously in your first select, from the error message.

Here is the [link](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/server-system-variables.html) for the mysql Manual page on system variables. `wait_timeout` and its brethren are often the culprits. In shared hosting environments, you are often out of luck. The timeouts can occur in 30 to 60 seconds. Need to strategize that, and scrutinize indices, or something more drastic.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem.

It wasn't my php code or the mysql server neither.
It was the hostip api I was calling for getting the user location, who just doesn't work anymore.

I changed for ipinfo and everything is back to normal.

Thanks.